References on maxima and minima serving as a pedagogical context to explore and gain a deeper understanding of real functions
The concept of a function is fundamental and plays a crucial role in various areas of mathematics. For instance, Dubinsky and Harel's book, The Concept of Function: Aspects of Epistemology and Pedagogy (1992), highlights several epistemological obstacles to understanding functions.
In this context, I believe that optimization problems (maxima and minima) provide an excellent setting to explore and gain a deeper understanding of real functions. These problems naturally bring up questions about the domain during the modeling process. Additionally, the practical nature of optimization problems tends to engage students' interest and attention. This setting also allows for the articulation of multiple representations: words, tables, graphs, and algebra, dynamic geometry.
To avoid relying on mere speculation, I am seeking references on the use of maxima and minima as a pedagogical tool to teach functions (including in high school, with and without Calculus). A quick search on Google Scholar did not yield results. Therefore, my question is: Do you know of any references or works on this topic?

I'd be surprised if such a reference existed. Concept A is introducing functions. Concept B is understanding a function's domain. Concept C is understanding minima and maxima. Concept D is using optimization to find minima and maxima. It seems like these would need to be taught in sequence, so using optimization (step D) to "teach functions" (step A) would be difficult instead of using optimization as a useful application and motivation for what was already taught.
